# No match for operator >> ... with int?

Tags: qt, operator-keyword

I'm overloading `operator >>` to read some class' variables from files.

I have this weird problem, apparently, it works for `QString`, `QStringList`, but not for `int`! I have already tried declaring my `int` as `qint16`, and I receive the same error message.

`.h` contains:

```
enum Anyo { Primero, Segundo, Tercero, Cuarto, Quinto, Sexto, ANYOS };

class Asignatura
{
public:
    Asignatura();
    Asignatura(const QString & nom, Anyo a, int hsCat);
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Asignatura &a);
    friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &in, Asignatura &a);
    ...

private:
    static int idGeneral;
    int id;
    QString nombre;
    QString nombreProfe;
    Anyo anyo;
    int hsCatedra;
    int hsResueltas;
    bool tieneProfe;
};
```

`.cpp` contains:

```
QDataStream& operator >>(QDataStream &in, Asignatura &a)
{
    in >> a.id;
    in >> a.nombre;
    in >> a.nombreProfe;
    in >> a.anyo;
    in >> a.hsCatedra;
    in >> a.hsResueltas;
    in >> a.tieneProfe;
    return in;
}
```

The errors I receive are:

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> a.Asignatura::id'
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> a.Asignatura::anyo'
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> a.Asignatura::hsCatedra'
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> a.Asignatura::hsResueltas'
error: no match for 'operator>>' in 'in >> a.Asignatura::tieneProfe'
```

What? You don't know how to read an `int`? Or a `bool` (wich is basically an `int`...)?

I'm using QDataStream::Qt_4_5 (for no special reason), Qt 4.8.3.

As I said above, I've already tried to declare variables as qint16, qint8. Didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Sidenote: a `bool` is not an `int`. The two are completely separate types in C++. There is an implicit conversion between the two types but they are certainly not the same.

Comment: `QDataStream` documentation explicitly supports `qint*` types, so this is very weird--perhaps you forgot to save changes before a test recompile or something.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#operator-gt-gt-7

Comment: Do you need to add `#include "name_of_header.h"` to the `.cpp` file?

Comment: No, it's already included.

Comment: Have you included `<QDataStream>` in the `.cpp` file?

Comment: @Natham That did make a difference! Thank you. I'm sorry for such a silly mistake. I'm new to Qt and I don't seem to get used to so many different Headers files. Tank you.Now the only one that isn't supported is the enum type. I guess I'll figure that out. Should I mark this question as "solved"? if so, where? Should I upvote on your comment? I don't see how?

Comment: I'll post it as an answer and then you can accept it.

Comment: Ok that will be later, I'm leaving now. Tanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `QDataStream` class is forward declared in one of the Qt header files you have included. Because of this, you can use the `QDataStream` type as a reference in the class definition without receiving an error.

However, attempting to do anything with an instance of the class (such as accessing `operator >>`) will result in an error because the definition is not available.

To fix this, simply add the following `#include` at the top of your `.cpp` file:

```
#include <QDataStream>
```

Comment: Great answer. Subtle detail. Thanks for teaching. I will vote up when I reach 15 points. Right now, I'm not allowed.